# Facebook redirect after Fb.login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement `FB.login()` on my site. I get 'Request for Permission' window and once user accepts it, I want to redirect him to my custom page (under the same domain). Where and how should I set it up in the code?

```
 <script>
        //initializing API
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({ appId: 'xxx', status: true, cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });
        };
        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        } ());

    function fblogin() {  
        FB.login(function (response) {
            //...
        }, { perms: 'user_birthday,user_location' });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should subscribe to the [`auth.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) event, something like:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ appId: 'xxx', status: true, cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(resp) {
        window.location = 'http://www.domain.com/custom_page.php';
    });
};
```

Comment: you may also wish to subscribe to auth.sessionChange for visitors who have already authorized your app and have come back to the original page.

Comment: @CameraSchoolDropout: True but I always use this with the PHP-SDK, so I handle these users by checking the session with `$fb->getSession()`. +1 btw

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<div id='loginmsg'>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email,publish_stream,read_stream" data-show-faces="true" data-width="720" data-max-rows="1"></div>
</div>


<script>
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(resp) {        
    $('#loginmsg').html("<h2>...just a moment...</h2>");
    window.location = '/logged-in.html';   
  });

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      $('#loginmsg').html("<h2>...just a moment...</h2>");
      window.location = '/logged-in.html';
    }
  });

</script>
```